# VB.NET persistent cookie exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies

I am attempting to add the text that a user types into the textbox 'textMain' to a cookie. I am trying to do this so there is no need to click a 'Save' button. Therefore a user could type a sentence and then close the browser and it would be saved. Here is the VB code; done on the load handler and the unload handler.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        If Request.Cookies("content") IsNot Nothing Then
            textMain.Text = Request.Cookies("content").Value.ToString
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Unload(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload
    '' If Request.Cookies("content") Is Nothing Then
    Dim contentCookie As New HttpCookie("content")
    contentCookie.Value = textMain.Text
    contentCookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue
    Response.Cookies.Add(contentCookie)
   '' End If
End Sub
```

The exception comes on the Respinse.Cookies.Add(contentCookie) line.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the exception ? BTW this might not work as planned because your cookie is not saved until your page is post back and/or recieve a request  which means user should press the submit button and if he closes his browser no post back will happen and no text is saved in the cookie

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Response is not available in this context.

Comment: This happens because Response is not available in Page_Unload

Comment: Take a look at this link please : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you! In that case, do you know how I could achieve saving the text to a cookie without a submit button (and without using response in the unload).

Comment: You can either use a client side cookie or use HTML 5 data storage that let us persist data in client side.Then you should bind to `change` event of the `input` tag of txtMain using for example JQuery or pure javascript and persist any changes then you can read back the saved data everytime the page is loaded in client side again